# Memory Managment In Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to free memory during the images are load in one by one memory.

I am working on Image Slideshow, and all images are bind with list. when play slideshow images are load one by one in memory, now i am trying that when 2nd image is shown the 1st image will remove from memory.
How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Drop all your references to image1, Dispose what needs to be disposed and wait for GC to do its magic.

Comment: Sir i am changing images in selection_changed event.

Comment: @Sajid, perhaps some code might make it easier to form a more specific answer.

Comment: Have you any example for Dispose()  ?